# Fortran matrix has dimensions 0,0 even though it is initialialized with dimensions 5,5

Tags: fortran

What is the cause of this?

```
27  recursive subroutine svd_jacobi(A, m, n, U, S, V)
28  
29    implicit none
30  
31    real(8) :: A(m,n)
32    real(8) :: B(n,n)
33    real(8) :: U(m,m)
34    real(8) :: S(m,n)
(gdb) p n 
$25 = 5
(gdb) whatis B
type = real(kind=8) (0,0)
(gdb) whatis n
type = integer(kind=8)
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your version of gdb doesn't fully understand the Fortran array descriptor. There's some improvements in the gdb Archer branch, which AFAIK isn't yet merged with trunk.

Comment: Valgrind is telling me that writes into the zero sized array are illegal. This indicates that there is a problem with the program and not just with GDB. But the write is happening in a subroutine `whatis B` returns `type = real(kind=8) (*,*)`. Could there be another problem?

Comment: Sure. Post a self-contained example and I'm sure I or someone else will be able to help you.